# .hide() div when timer reaches 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown

I have been trying to make a timer disappear when it reaches 00:00 but everytime I try something it just hides the div right away.

Here is the code I am using:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var $worked = $("#worked");

  function update() {
    var myTime = $worked.html();
    var ss = myTime.split(":");
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setHours(0);
    dt.setMinutes(ss[0]);
    dt.setSeconds(ss[1]);

    var dt2 = new Date(dt.valueOf() - 1000);
    var temp = dt2.toTimeString().split(" ");
    var ts = temp[0].split(":");

    $worked.html(ts[1] + ":" + ts[2]);
    setTimeout(update, 1000);
  }

  setTimeout(update, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="worked">00:10</div>
```

Comment: so the initial html of `#worked` is empty?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/olaxoj/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Not sure what you're seeing, but when I made your code a snippet, it counts down to "00:00" then starts counting down from "59:59". I do note you're not calling `.hide()` anywhere...

Comment: When I add `alert(dt);` after you call .setHours, etc - I get "Invalid Date"...

Comment: I took the .hide() out to avoid confusion and just gave the source of the code I am using. Add any time value in mm:ss format inside the #worked div and it'll begin to count down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an example for you. For this example I have changed the timer's interval to 10ms so you can see the result quicker. Also instead of setting a `setTimeout` to run `update` inside the function `update`. You can use `setInterval`. I have also added a check inside the update function that checks if the time is `00:00`. If it is true, then it invalidates the interval by calling `clearInterval(timer);` and runs `$worked.hide()`

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        var $worked = $("#worked");
        var timer = setInterval(update, 10);

        function update() {
            var myTime = $worked.html();
            var ss = myTime.split(":");
            var dt = new Date();
            dt.setHours(0);
            dt.setMinutes(ss[0]);
            dt.setSeconds(ss[1]);

            var dt2 = new Date(dt.valueOf() - 1000);
            var temp = dt2.toTimeString().split(" ");
            var ts = temp[0].split(":");
            $worked.html(ts[1]+":"+ts[2]);
            $worked.html(ts[1]+":"+ts[2]);

            if(ts[1] === '00' && ts[2] === '00') {
                clearInterval(timer);
                $worked.hide();
            }
        }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="worked">01:00</div>
```

Comment: This seems to count down very very quickly

Comment: Yes,  For this example I have changed the timer's interval to 10ms so you can see the result quicker. Just change the timer's interval to 1000.
`var timer = setInterval(update, 10);` to `var timer = setInterval(update, 1000);`

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help you. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var $worked = $("#timer");
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var now, currentDistance;

  setInterval(function update() {
    now = new Date().getTime();
    currentDistance = 10000 - now + startTime;

    if (currentDistance > 0) {
        $worked.html(parseInt(currentDistance / 1000) + " seconds, " + (currentDistance % 1000) + " ms left!");
    } else {
        $worked.hide();
    }
  }, 1);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer" style="background-color: rgb(190, 190, 220); width: 200px; text-align: center"></div>
```